# Prestashop doesn't load module data on displayAdminProductsExtra hook

Tags: prestashop-1.7, prestashop-modules

[The problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JpYIv.png)

I've spent hours to find out the possible problem and even tried to look into the prestashop code.
But it will take too much time to read it. What can be the problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I shouldn't aks the question. 
at `public function install()`

the

`parent::install();`

must be ALWAYS before any

`$this->registerHook`